# How do you access specific rows and columns in tkinter treeview which are not selected

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

as the title says, i'm trying to access specific data from treeview (or rather all date from a column, but one row at a time), but i can't seem to figure out how to access any data from treeview except one already selected

If its relevant i'm using modified code from codewithFaraz (https://www.codewithfaraz.com/python/17/create-a-task-management-system-in-python-with-tkinter), but i replaces priority and die date with number values

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import datetime


class Task:
    def __init__(self, name, priority, due_date):
        self.name = name
        self.priority = priority
        self.due_date = due_date


class TaskManagerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Task Manager")

        self.tasks = []

        self.task_name_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.priority_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.due_date_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Task Name Label and Entry
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Task Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        task_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.task_name_var)
        task_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Priority Label and Dropdown
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Priority:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        priority_values = ["Low", "Medium", "High"]
        priority_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(self.root, textvariable=self.priority_var, values=priority_values)
        priority_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Due Date Label and Calendar
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Due Date:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        due_date_entry = DateEntry(self.root, textvariable=self.due_date_var, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
        due_date_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Add Task Button
        add_task_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Add Task", command=self.add_task)
        add_task_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Task List Treeview
        self.task_list_treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=("Priority", "Due Date"))
        self.task_list_treeview.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.task_list_treeview.heading("#0", text="Task Name")
        self.task_list_treeview.heading("Priority", text="Priority")
        self.task_list_treeview.heading("Due Date", text="Due Date")

        # Delete Task Button
        delete_task_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete Task", command=self.delete_task)
        delete_task_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")

        # Clear Task Button
        clear_task_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Clear Task", command=self.clear_task)
        clear_task_button.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="e")

    def add_task(self):
        name = self.task_name_var.get()
        priority = self.priority_var.get()
        due_date = self.due_date_var.get()

        if name and priority and due_date:
            task = Task(name, priority, due_date)
            self.tasks.append(task)

            self.task_list_treeview.insert("", tk.END, text=task.name, values=(task.priority, task.due_date))

            self.task_name_var.set("")
            self.priority_var.set("")
            self.due_date_var.set("")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill in all fields.")

    def delete_task(self):
        selected_item = self.task_list_treeview.selection()
        if selected_item:
            task_name = self.task_list_treeview.item(selected_item)["text"]
            for task in self.tasks:
                if task.name == task_name:
                    self.tasks.remove(task)
                    self.task_list_treeview.delete(selected_item)
                    break

    def clear_task(self):
        self.task_name_var.set("")
        self.priority_var.set("")
        self.due_date_var.set("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TaskManagerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Can anybody please help me with this, how do you access specific items by columns in treeview, one by one?

Comment: Use [`Treeview.set`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M57).

Comment: Thank you, but can you please give me an example, i think i'm doing something wrong, probably not sending right values to set()

Comment: You need to pass the row ID and column name.

Comment: I'm guessing column names in this case are #0, Priority and Due Date, or that i can access it by column number, but how do i get rowID? I tried I001, but it didn't work. Again, can you please write an example so i know what i'm looking for?

Comment: The row ID is the value returned by `Treeview.insert()` or the value to the option `iid` in `Treeview.insert()`.  If the values in `#0` column are unique, then you can set it as the value of `iid` option when inserting data and use it as the row ID.

Comment: Thank you very much, i managed to resolve it by using get_children(), everything works perfectly except when there are no children. Do you maybe know whats the value of get_children() for empty Treeview? I tried "". Null, None, False and a few others, neither seems right

Comment: It is `()` and it is easy to know by just calling `.get_children()` after creating the instance of `Treeview`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't consider trying that, but i may be a bit tired. I find that after sleeping on a problem i wake up with many new ideas :)

Comment: This is resolved, this was exactly what i needed, thanks again!